# Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry with a common Rails Asssociation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a straight forward `has_and_belongs_to_many` association :

```
class CardSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :emails
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :card_signups
end
```

If I assigned the email to one ID it works alright..

```
User.find(y) << Email.find(10)
```

But if I try to assign the same email to another user, I get this :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `card_signups_emails` (`id`, `card_signup_id`, `email_id`) VALUES (10, 1505, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok in order to solve this you need to make sure when using HABTM associations, that you set your tables to false id's. As so :

```
create_table(:emails_users, :id => false) do |t|
  t.string :user_id
  t.string :email_id
end
```